# KeyError: 'fields', but key 'fields' is works at the same time

Tags: python, django

This is kind of weird: The print wint `ex_pur['fields']` is working, and at the same time I have a `KeyError: 'fields'` abote this `print()`. Halp me please to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

```
class Purchases (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Purchase')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Description')
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    list = models.ForeignKey('Lists', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='List')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Purchases'
        verbose_name = 'Purchase'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} {self.name}"
```

```
        ...
        try:
            existed_purchases_queryset = Purchases.objects.filter(name__in=purchases_names, list_id=list_id)
            existed_purchases = serializers.serialize('python', existed_purchases_queryset)
            response["existed"] = existed_purchases
            print(f"----------------\n{existed_purchases = }\n----------------")
            existed_purchases_names = [pur['fields']['name'] for pur in existed_purchases]
        except Purchases.DoesNotExist:
            print("Все позиции новые.")
        for purchase in purchases:
            print(f"{type(existed_purchases[0]) = }")
            purchases_serializer = PurchaseAddSerializer(data=purchase)
            do = False
            if purchase['name'] in existed_purchases_names:
                for ex_pur in existed_purchases:
                    print(f"----------------\n{('description' in **ex_pur['fields']**.keys()) = }\n----------------")
                    if ex_pur['fields']['name'] == purchase['name']:
                        ...
```

```
----------------
('description' in ex_pur['fields'].keys()) = True
----------------
----------------
('description' in ex_pur['fields'].keys()) = True
----------------
----------------
('description' in ex_pur['fields'].keys()) = True
----------------
Internal Server Error: /purchases/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line
 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197,
 in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 6
5, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104,
 in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in d
ispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in h
andle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in r
aise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\.venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in d
ispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lars5\OneDrive\Programming\Python\shopping_list_telegram_bo
t_02_django\list\views.py", line 183, in post
    print(f"----------------\n{('description' in **ex_pur['fields']**.keys()) = 
}\n----------------")
                                                 ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
**KeyError: 'fields'**
[03/Feb/2024 18:11:32] "POST /purchases/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 99390
```

tried:
to check types: ex_pur is dict.
to check is `"fields"` in `ex_pur.keys()` - True;
to ask copilot in different weys -- nothing useful;
to print keys: `"ex_pur.keys() = dict_keys(['model', 'pk', 'fields'])`
", and key `'fields'` exists;

I don't know what to do else. I've already spent 2 houers for this proplem...

Comment: Can you share the `Purchase` model? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: What is the f-string expression `('description' in **ex_pur['fields']**.keys()) = ` supposed to produce?

Comment: I figured out! I added different tree tipe dicts in the list, so some dicts didn't have key 'fields'. I fixed it! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out! I added different tree tipe dicts in the existed_purchases list, so some dicts in it realy didn't have key 'fields', so that was the problem. I fixed it! Thank you for help!